# Kubernetes mock test post body

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, kubernetes

We are using `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.server.mock.KubernetesServer` in our unit test to test the interaction with the k8s server.

Is there a way to test the sent body for example a post request to k8s server?

For example

```
kubernetesServer.expect().put() //
    .withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps/{}", namespace, configMapName)) //
    .andReturn(200, configMap) //
    .once();
```

we would like to verify, that our code send the correct ConfigMap data to the k8s server.

Did we miss something, or is it really not available?